# Inserting date time in zulu time format into datetime column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert '2009-03-04T17:49:20Z' which is in zulu time into datetime type column of mysql table.
Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_to_date()` to parse your date format like this:

```
set myDate = str_to_date('2009-03-04T17:49:20Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
```

Comment: but how to insert it, like when I create a table what will I write in the ZULU time column? Plese help