# How to fix DATETIME truncation warnings while uploading CSV data into mySQL using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, csv, nodes

I am getting CSV data (from a url using NPM request) which I upload into mySQL using Nodejs. This CSV data has created_at column with value '2015-10-19T04:00:00Z'. While uploading in mySQL, I want to change the format of this column to "10/19/2015 4:00:00 AM".

The mySQL table has created_at column with datatype DATETIME. However when I upload '2015-10-19T04:00:00Z' into it, it gives :- 
warning message is :    Message: 'Data truncated for column \'created_at\' at row 24'. How can I change the data format before inserting values in mySQL table in NodeJS?

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var csvParser = require('csv-parse');
request(options, function (error, response, csvbody) { ...
csvParser(csvbody, { delimiter: ','}, function(err, data) { ...
con.query("INSERT INTO ?? VALUES ?", [mySQLTable, data], function(err, result) {...
```

Comment: How to convert Zulu time to a MySQL acceptable format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819295/inserting-date-time-in-zulu-time-format-into-datetime-column-in-mysql

Comment: Dont try and change the format to `10/19/2015 4:00:00 AM` This you do in the presentation layer if thats how a user wants to see it. MySQL Date and DateTime columns expect dates and times in a fixed format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`

Comment: Thankyou. I do know of ways to convert date format in mySQL. But not in this particular situation. Can you please see my Reply to `Alessandro's` suggestion below and provide you suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Adding your user name so that you get a notification

Comment: Inserting `'2015-10-19T04:00:00Z'` into a DATETIME column should work !!! You cannot load `10/19/2015 4:00:00 AM` into a DATETIME column. If your users want to see the date as `10/19/2015 4:00:00 AM` You should do that in your presentation layer and NOT store dates and times like that on the database

Answer (score 0):

try to use the following statement instead yours:

```
con.query("INSERT INTO ?? (field_name) VALUES (timestamp(substr('?',1,14)))", [mySQLTable, data], function(err, result) {...
```

It should work.

Comment: The problem is `data` here is the output of `csv-parse`and there are many other columns as well. `timestamp` above would work if data has only 1 column. How can I apply `timestamp` to ONLY that particular column within data. ANy help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I found a partial solution to my comment above using below code. 
But other columns are now blank and also substring does not work. 
Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: `csvParser(csvbody, { delimiter: ',', cast: function(value, context){if(context.index === 5){ return `substring(${value},1,19)}else{return context}},}, `